# Odoo Restrict access to database Manager page

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

How can I restrict access to database Manager page, by a password, for Odoo / OpenERP? So only master admin can see this page.

I found a good module here:
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-show-the-manage-database-page-for-particular-user-like-administrator-in-openerp-v8-57036#answer-64736

But the problem is this module does not support multiple databases!

Is there any other method or custom module to achieve that ?

Comment: way you are use multiple database in database manager page?

Comment: I just create two databases with the normal way (from database manager page). For the module listed above, I installed it in both databases but then the password page created by this module return 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the '/web/database/controller' and put the condition to check whether the session's user is admin or not , if it's admin then return the original page which is returned by odoo else you can show your page showing that you can't access this.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this module: [Restrict access to Manage Databases](https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/restrict_db_mgr/) to restrict access to the Manage Databases page.

After installing the module, you will only be able to visit the Manage Databases page (`/web/database/manager/`) if you are signed in as the Administrator (with user ID = 1) or you have Technical Features enabled for that user.

If you have installed the module and are unable to switch databases while logged out, you can add the `db` flag to your url to manually select the database that you want, for example:

`yoursite.com/web?db=database2`

**Caveat:**

This solution might be troublesome as you will have to install it in all your databases on the same instance.

The other solution will be to use nginx to restrict access to `/web/database/manager` to only your IP address or a range or IP addresses.